# How to dynamically hide first 'N' DT & DD tags through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, hide

I am generating a DB Report with Description Tags, where I want to hide the first DT/DD Elements (* as they are the result of Null Values, which I can't skip).

The Markup is being generated like this...

```
<dl>
 <h3 style="text-align: center">01-SEP-2018</h3>
  <h3>
  <dt >
     Time Slot
  </dt>
  <dd >
     UNASSIGNED
  </dd>
  <dt >
     Morning Shift
  </dt>
  <dd >
     <label for="f01_0000">Morning Shift</label>
     <select name="f01" id="f01_0000">
        <option value="NULL" selected="selected">UNASSIGN</option>
        <option value="Aslam">Aslam</option>
        <option value="Brock">Brock</option>
     </select>
  </dd>
  <dt >
     Evening Shift
  </dt>
  <dd >
     <label for="f02_0000">Evening Shift</label>
     <select name="f02"  id="f02_0000">
        <option value="NULL" selected="selected">UNASSIGN</option>
        <option value="Aslam">Aslam</option>
        <option value="Brock">Brock</option>
     </select>
  </dd>
  <dt >
     Resource Type
  </dt>
  <dd >
     UNASSIGNED
  </dd>
  <dt >
     Port Code
  </dt>
  <dd >
     UNASSIGNED
  </dd>
  <dt >
     Time Slot
  </dt>
  <dd >
     8
  </dd>
  <dt >
     Morning Shift
  </dt>
  <dd >
     <label for="f01_0001">Morning Shift</label>
     <select name="f01">
        <option value="NULL">UNASSIGN</option>
        <option value="Aslam">Aslam</option>
        <option value="Brock" selected="selected">Brock</option>

     </select>
  </dd>
  <dt >
     Evening Shift
  </dt>
  <dd >
     <label for="f02_0001">Evening Shift</label>
     <select name="f02" id="f02_0001">
        <option value="NULL">UNASSIGN</option>
        <option value="Aslam" selected="selected">Aslam</option>
        <option value="Brock">Brock</option>
     </select>
  </dd>
  <dt >
     Resource Type
  </dt>
  <dd >
     SKIPPER
  </dd>
  <dt >
     Port Code
  </dt>
  <dd >
     AEKHL
  </dd>
</h3>
<h3 style="text-align: center">05-SEP-2018</h3>
<h3>
  <dt >
     Time Slot
  </dt>
  <dd >
     8
  </dd>
  <dt >
     Morning Shift
  </dt>
  <dd >
     <label for="f01_0002" >Morning Shift</label>
     <select name="f01" >
        <option value="NULL">UNASSIGN</option>
        <option value="Aslam" selected="selected">Aslam</option>
        <option value="Brock">Brock</option>

     </select>
  </dd>
  <dt >
     Evening Shift
  </dt>
  <dd >
     <label for="f02_0002"  >Evening Shift</label>
     <select name="f02" >
        <option value="NULL">UNASSIGN</option>
        <option value="Aslam">Aslam</option>
        <option value="Brock" selected="selected">Brock</option>

     </select>
  </dd>
  <dt >
     Resource Type
  </dt>
  <dd >
     SKIPPER
  </dd>
  <dt >
     Port Code
  </dt>
  <dd >
     AEKHL
  </dd>
 </h3>
</dl>
```

I want to hide the first DT & DD tags where by default UNASSIGNED is being generated. To do this, I wrote a small snippet of Jquery, to be executed with Page Loading

```
$("dl").find("dt").each(function() {
var count = 0;
$(this).nextUntil("dt").filter(function() {
  return count++ >1;
 }).hide();
});
```

This worked previously with a similar kind of problem, but unfortunately, I am not able to fix in this case.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
    $("dl").find("dd").each(function() {
        var $thisDD = $(this);

        if( 
            $.trim($thisDD.text()) == 'UNASSIGNED'
            ||
            $thisDD.find('select').val() == 'NULL'
        ) {
            $thisDD.hide();
            $thisDD.prev('dt').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Works fine on JSFiddle, but not working on my actual code. I executed this on PageLoad. But still the elements are there

Comment: which version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: Jquery is 2.1.3